# Android bluetooth LE write is not working

Tags: android

I am new to App development. I am developing an Android APP to read and write to and from a Bluetooth module ( Microchip RN4871).  Using the BlutoothLeGatt sample program, I am able to scan and connect to the Bluetooth module. When I write, It is accepting . There is no error message. I am getting below in the run window of android studio, when I press the buttons.

> D/ViewRootImpl@70a8843[DeviceControlActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage
>   processPointer 0 D/ViewRootImpl@70a8843[DeviceControlActivity]:
>   ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

I am using below object for write.

```
  /get the write characteristic from the service/
    public void writeCustomCharacteristic(int value) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
   /check if the service is available on the device/
        BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455"));
        if(mCustomService == null){
            Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
            return;
        }
           /get the write characteristic from the service/
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("49535343-8841-43f4-a8d4-ecbe34729bb3"));
        mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(value,android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8,0);
        if(mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic) == false){
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to write characteristic");
        }
    }
```

I know the problem is with `mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(value,android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8,0);`

Please let me know, What mistake I did on this instruction.